# Calculating a value range in percent

Tags: php, algorithm, math, formula, percentage

The following function takes a DPI value and returns a percentage:

```
    100%        if the value is bigger than 200
    50% to 100% if the value is between 100 and 200
    25% to 50%  if the value is between 80 and 100
    0%  to 25%  if the value is lower than 80

    static public function interpretDPI($x) {
        if ($x >= 200) return 100;
        if ($x >= 100 && $x < 200) return 50 + 50 * (($x - 100) / 100);
        if ($x >= 80 && $x < 100) return 25 + 25 * (($x - 80) / 20);
        if ($x < 80) return 25 * ($x / 80);
    }
```

Now i have to change this function according to these rules, returning:

```
    100%        if the value is bigger than 100
    75% to 100% if the value is between 72 and 100
    50% to 75%  if the value is between 50 and 72
    0%  to 50%  if the value is lower than 50
```

In order to achieve this, i tried to re-model the function according to how i understood its behaviour:

```
    static public function interpretDPI($x) {
        if ($x >= 100) return 100;
        if ($x >= 72 && $x < 100) return 75 + 75 * (($x - 72) / 28);
        if ($x >= 50 && $x < 72) return 50 + 50 * (($x - 50) / 22);
        if ($x < 50) return 25 * ($x / 50);
    }
```

But the results are plain wrong. A DPI of 96 for instance will give me 141% as a result. Obviously this is wrong but i lack the mathematical understanding to know why - and how to fix it.

I must have misunderstood something about how the function works.

Can anyone elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the right idea but the coefficient numbers in your formulas are wrong, which get you results like 141%.

You should try this :

```
  static public function interpretDPI($x) {
   if ($x > 100) return 100;
   if ($x > 72 && $x <= 100) return 75 + 25 * (($x - 72) / 28);
   if ($x >= 50 && $x <= 72) return 50 + 25 * (($x - 50) / 22);
   if ($x < 50) return 50 * ($x / 50);
  }
```

I think you'll get the results you want, I checked it, it looks good :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the function code like this

```
 static public function interpretDPI($x) {
    if ($x > 100) return 100;
    if ($x > 72 && $x <= 100) return 75 + 75 * (($x - 72) / 28);
    if ($x >= 50 && $x <= 72) return 50 + 50 * (($x - 50) / 22);
    if ($x < 50) return 25 * ($x / 50);
 }
```

It will work according to your requirement

Comment: Thank You! But this is exactly what i have written myself, with the only difference being in the range limits (great than, lower than). I tried it and it returns 139 if i call interpretDPI(96);